# Finding function from given sequence?

Tags: series-expansion, maple

I only have six numbers,  $\lbrace4, 48, 360, 2240, 12600, 66528\rbrace$, from the following series:

```
Table[1/SeriesCoefficient[ArcSin[x/2]^2, {x, 0, 2 n}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

I want to find a function $f(x)$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)x^{2n}=\arcsin^2 \bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)$$

The is a Maple code to find it

> ```
> with(gfun)
>
> s := [seq(1/coeff(series(arcsin((1/2)*x)^2, x, 25), x, 2*n), n = 1 .. 12)]
>
> R := unapply(rsolve(op(1, listtorec(s, r(m))), r(m)), m); [seq(R(m), m = 0 .. 8)]
> ```

[image: Maple result]

How do I find it using *Mathematica*?

Comment: `Assuming[n >= 1, 1/SeriesCoefficient[ArcSin[Sqrt[x]/2]^2, {x, 0, n}]]` yields a rather complicated expression.

Comment: The left side of your equation is independent of `x`, but the right side is not.  Do you mean `Sum[f[n] x^(2 n), {n, 1, Infinity}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the result of `SeriesCoefficient[]` is that the hypergeometric functions that show up in it are left unsimplified:

```
Assuming[n >= 0, FullSimplify[1/SeriesCoefficient[ArcSin[Sqrt[x]/2]^2/x, {x, 0, n}]]]
   (2^(3 + 2 n) (1 + 2 n) Sqrt[π] Gamma[2 + n])/
   (Gamma[1/2 + n] ((1 + 2 n) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, -n}, {3/2, 1/2 - n}, 1] +
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, -(1/2) - n, -n}, {1/2 - n, 1/2 - n}, 1]))
```

Note, however, that since `n` is assumed to be a positive integer, the hypergeometric functions in it are actually *terminating* hypergeometric series; that is, one of the Pochhammer factors in the term becomes zero past a certain index. In particular, we can make the replacements

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, -n}, {3/2, 1/2 - n}, 1] ->
Sum[(Pochhammer[1/2, k]^2 (-1)^k Binomial[n, k])/
    (Pochhammer[3/2, k] Pochhammer[1/2 - n, k]), {k, 0, n}]

HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, -1/2 - n, -n}, {1/2 - n, 1/2 - n}, 1] ->
Sum[(Pochhammer[1/2, k] Pochhammer[-1/2 - n, k] (-1)^k Binomial[n, k])/
    Pochhammer[1/2 - n, k]^2, {k, 0, n}]
```

which respectively evaluate to `(π (n!)^2)/(2 (1/2 (-1 + 2 n))! (1/2 (1 + 2 n))!)` and `(π (n!)^2)/((1/2 (-1 + 2 n))!)^2`; if we plug these into the original expression returned by `SeriesCoefficient[]`, we have

```
FullSimplify[(2^(2 n + 3) (2 n + 1) Sqrt[π] Gamma[2 + n])/
             (Gamma[1/2 + n] ((2 n + 1) π (n!)^2/(2 ((2 n - 1)/2)! ((2 n + 1)/2)!) +
              π (n!)^2/(((2 n - 1)/2)!)^2))]
   (2^(3 + 2 n) (1 + n) Gamma[3/2 + n])/(Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 + n])
```

The result can of course be further simplified to `2^(2 n + 2) (n + 1) Pochhammer[3/2, n]/n!`.